# Need of declaration of a variable in a for loop

Tags: java, variables, for-loop

I am newbie but cannot find the answer to this question after looking thoroughly in other questions.

Why is there a need sometimes to declare a variable and sometimes not? I give you two examples:

Example 1: here, we don't have to declare `i` before the for loop.

```
class ForDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
```

Example 2: Here we *need* to declare `i` before the loop.

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] arrayOfInts = { 
            { 32, 87, 3, 589 },
            { 12, 1076, 2000, 8 },
            { 622, 127, 77, 955 }
        };
        int searchfor = 12;

        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

    search:
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length;
                 j++) {
                if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor) {
                    foundIt = true;
                    break search;
                }
            }
        }

        if (foundIt) {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
        } else {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
```

I will appreciate if you could also tell me why do I have also to initialize the variable `j = 0` if within the for loop I am already assigning the value 0.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Begin with the most narrow block. And only when you need, move it "up".

Comment: Because you use it after the closing } of the for loop. The scope ends there so you have to declare the variable so it can be accessed afterwards.

Maybe you should read a bit about scopes.

Comment: The variable doesn't live after its scope ends.

Comment: because you are accessing `i` variable after for loop execution. variables defines in `for` have scope only till loop execution.

Comment: as for j, there is no guarantee your loops will run, so if you would try to print it after the loops, it would need to be set

Comment: I'd like to encourage you to experiment yourself: what happens when you move the `int i` declaration into the `for` loop? The compiler shows you an error when you try to print the `i` value outside of the loop (or generalized, outside of the block where `i` is declared).

Comment: As for the `j` initialization: Without it, the compiler complains about a possibly missing initialization when you want to print `j`. So the reasoning could go like this: Where do I initialize `j`? In the `j=0` part of the inner loop. Is there a chance that this doesn't happen? Yes, if the inner loop isn't started at all, which happens if the outer loop iterates 0 times. And that can happen (as far as the compiler knows) if the array has 0 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the loop variable within the loop, it is only accessible inside the loop.

Since, in your last snippet, you are accessing both `i` and `j` after the loop ends (in `System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);`), you must declare them before the loop.

That's also the reason why you have to initialize `j` prior to the loop. The loop may never be executed (if `arrayOfInts.length` is 0), but you would still access `j` in the mentioned `println` statement, so it must be initialized at this point.

Answer (score 2):

In Example 1, i is only used within the for-loop. That's why you do not need to declare it beforehand. In Example 2, i is used in the loop, but also afterwards in the "if (foundIt)"-Block. Therefore, it must be declared outside the loop.